# How to create a fixed headerpanel with input shiny

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a datatable that scrolls in my shiny app.  But I would like to place some input fields that stay static above it as it does.  Right now the input fields are on the same fluidPage so they scroll up and away as the user scrolls down.

```
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             selectInput("category1", "Event Type:",
                         c(event_type),selected = "Music")),

      column(3,
             selectInput("category2", "Event Type:",
                         c(event_type),selected = "Music")),

      column(3,
             selectInput("city", "City:",
                         city_array,selected = "Gettysburg")),

      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               DT::dataTableOutput('table')
        ), 

        fluidPage(
          column(3,
                 selectInput("city", "City:",
                             city_array,selected = "Gettysburg"))

        )

        )
    ))
```

Comment: How are you rendering the table on the server side?

Comment: Like this:   
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(cal3, rownames = F, escape = F,
          options=list(lengthMenu=c(5,10,25,50,100),
          pageLength=page_length,
         searchHighlight=TRUE,
       autoWidth=F,
       columnDefs=list(list(width="50px",className = 'dt-top',targets=0:4),
     list(width="250px",targets=1),
     list(width="50px",targets=2)))